# sql statement how to keep null value

Tags: sql, oracle

This query here is executed on 3 tables(students) one which makes a zero on the exam so his q.correctanswer != ur.response, how can I keep the 0 value in my output.  When i execute this statement it only gives me two values instead of 3 for each student.

```
select count(*) as Test1
from users u, question q, userresponse ur
where q.eno = '1' 
  and q.eno = ur.eno 
  and q.qno = ur.qno 
  and ur.response = q.correctanswer 
  and u.uno = ur.uno
group by u.uno
```

sample data:

Note:
- "||" is used to concatenate strings
- each string is between a pair of single quotes.
- each record is between "(" and ")".
- fields are ordered according to fields in tables
- "\n" means a new line

> ======exams data==========
>
> (1,'Java Programming',60,1)
>
> (3,'Elementary History',10,3)
>
> ======questions data===========
>
> (1,1,'Choose the operations that can be performed on String
>   objects:(A) +\n(B) + =\n(C) -\n(D) %\n(E) ^','B')
>
> (1,2,'What will be the result of the expression\na % b\nwhen a and b
>   are of type int and their values are a = -17 and b = -6?','A')
>
> (1,3,'What will be the result of the expression\na % b\nwhen a and b
>   are of type int and their values are a = 10 and b = 6?','B')
>
> (1,4,'Consider the following code:\nint x, y, z\ny = 1\nz = 5\nx = 0
>   - (++y) + z++\nAfter execution of this, what will be the values of x, y and z?','C')
>
> (1,5,'Identify the statements that are correct:\n(A) int a = 13,
>   a>>2 = 3\n(B) int b = -8, b>>1 = -4\n(C) int a = 13, a>>>2 = 3\n(D)
>   int b = -8, b>>>1 = -4','E')
>
> (1,6,'If not assigned a value, a variable of type char has the
>   following default value:','A')
>
> (1,7,'What will be the value of a after execution of the following
>   statements:\nint a = 23, b = 34\na = ((a < b) ? (b + a) : (b -
>   a)','B')
>
> (1,8,'Which of the following is not a hexadecimal number?\n(A)
>   999\n(B) (hex)23\n(C) 0x556\n(D) 0x1F2','C')
>
> (1,9,'if(check4Biz(storeNum) != null) {}\nReferring to the above,
>   what datatype could be returned by method check4Biz()?','D')
>
> (1,10,'Select the invalid assignment statements from the
>   following:\n(A) float x = 238.88\n(B) double y = 0x443\n(C) int n =
>   (int) true\n(D) long m =778645','A')
>
> (1,11,'int j\nfor(int i=0i<14i++) {\nif(i<10) {\nj = 2 +
>   i\n}\nSystem.out.println("j: " + j + " i: " + i)\n}\nWhat is WRONG
>   with the above code?','E')
>
> (1,12,'Consider the following code:\nclass ClassA\n{\npublic static
>   void main(String args [ ])\n{\nClassB b = classB()\n}\nClassA(int x) {
>   }\n}\nclass ClassB extends ClassA\n{\n}\nWhat will happen when we
>   compile and run this code?','A')
>
> (1,13,'The keywords reserved but not used in the initial version of
>   Java are:\n(A) union\n(B) const\n(C) inner\n(D) goto\n(E) boolean\n(F)
>   synchronized','C')
>
> (1,14,'We would like to make a member of a class visible in all
>   subclasses regardless of what package they are in. Which one of the
>   following keywords would achieve this?','D')
>
> (1,15,'Which of the following are not keywords?\n(A) NULL\n(B)
>   implements\n(C) protected\n(D) extended\n(E) string','B')
>
> (3,1,'The Battle of Gettysburg was fought during which war?','C')
>
> (3,2,'Neil Armstrong and Buzz Aldrin walked how many \n' ||
>          'minutes on the moon in 1696?','B')
>
> (3,3,'Which Presidents held office during World War II?','D')
>
> (3,4,'In a communist economic system, people:','B')
>
> (3,5,'Which president did not die while in office?','D')
>
> (3,6,'Which state refused to attend the Constitutional Convention
>   \n' ||
>          'in 1787 because it didn''t want the United States government \n' ||
>          'to interfere with already established state affairs?','A')
>
> (3,7,'Who founded Buddhism?','A')
>
> (3,8,'Where is India?','D')
>
> (3,9,'What is the dominant religion in India?','B')
>
> (3,10,'Near which river did archaeologists find India''s \n' ||
>           'first civilization?','B')
>
> ========== answerOption data ============
>
> (3,8,'A','Australia')  (3,8,'B','America')  (3,8,'C','Africa') 
>   (3,8,'D','Asia')  (3,1,'A','World War II')  (3,1,'B','The
>   Revolutionary War') (3,1,'C','The Civil War') (3,1,'D','World War I')
>   (3,2,'A','123')  (3,2,'B','None')  (3,2,'C','10')  (3,2,'D','51') 
>   (3,3,'A','Franklin D. Roosevelt')  (3,3,'B','Dwight D. Eisenhower') 
>   (3,3,'C','Harry Truman')  (3,3,'D','Both A and C')  (3,4,'A','Are
>   forced to work as slaves')  (3,4,'B','Work for the common good') 
>   (3,4,'C','Work from home computers')  (3,4,'D','Don''t work')
>   (3,5,'A','John F. Kennedy')  (3,5,'B','Franklin D. Roosevelt') 
>   (3,5,'C','Abraham Lincoln')  (3,5,'D','Ronald Reagan') 
>   (3,5,'E','James A. Garfield')  (3,7,'A','Siddharta Gautama') 
>   (3,7,'B','Jesus Christ')  (3,7,'C','Mahatma Gandhi') 
>   (3,7,'D','Muhammad')  (3,6,'A','Rhode Island')  (3,6,'B','New
>   Hampshire')  (3,6,'C','New Jersey')  (3,6,'D','New York') 
>   (3,9,'A','Islam')  (3,9,'B','Hinduism')  (3,9,'C','Christianity') 
>   (3,9,'D','Buddhism')   (3,10,'A','The Tiber River')  (3,10,'B','The
>   Indus River')  (3,10,'C','The Yellow River')  (3,10,'D','The Nile
>   River') (1,1,'A','(D) & (E)') (1,1,'B',' (A) & (B)') (1,1,'C','(D)')
>   (1,1,'D','(A)') (1,1,'E','None of these') (1,2,'A','-17')
>   (1,2,'B','5') (1,2,'C','3') (1,2,'D','-5') (1,2,'E','None of these')
>   (1,3,'A','1.66') (1,3,'B','4') (1,3,'C','2') (1,3,'D','1')
>   (1,3,'E','None of these') (1,4,'A','x = 4, y = 1, z = 5') (1,4,'B',' x
>   = -7, y = 1, z = 5') (1,4,'C','x = 3, y = 2, z = 6') (1,4,'D',' x = 4, y = 2, z = 6') (1,4,'E',' x = 8, y = 2, z = 1') (1,5,'A','(C) & (D) ')
>   (1,5,'B',' (A), (B) & (C) ') (1,5,'C','(A), (B), (C) & (D)')
>   (1,5,'D','(A) & (B) ') (1,5,'E','None of the above')
>   (1,6,'A','\uffff') (1,6,'B','\u0000') (1,6,'C','" " (space)')
>   (1,6,'D','\u0001') (1,6,'E','None of the above') (1,7,'A','23')
>   (1,7,'B','Error. Cannot be executed.') (1,7,'C','57') (1,7,'D','11')
>   (1,7,'E','34') (1,8,'A','(A), (B) & (C)') (1,8,'B','(C)')
>   (1,8,'C','(A) & (B) ') (1,8,'D','(A)') (1,8,'E','(D)')
>   (1,9,'A','Boolean') (1,9,'B','Int') (1,9,'C','String')
>   (1,9,'D','Char') (1,9,'E','Byte') (1,10,'A','(A) & (C)')
>   (1,10,'B','(A) & (B)') (1,10,'C','(B) ') (1,10,'D','(B) & (D) ')
>   (1,10,'E','(D)') (1,11,'A','Integer "j" is not initialized.')
>   (1,11,'B','Nothing.') (1,11,'C','You cannot declare integer i inside
>   the for-loop declaration.') (1,11,'D','The syntax of the "if"
>   statement is incorrect.') (1,11,'E','You cannot print integer values
>   without converting them to strings.') (1,12,'A','Will compile and run
>   successfully ') (1,12,'B','Error. ClassA does not define a no-argument
>   constructor ') (1,12,'C','Error. There is no code in the constructor
>   ClassA(int x) ') (1,12,'D','Error. ClassB does not define a
>   no-argument constructor ') (1,12,'E','Error. There is no code in the
>   class ClassB ') (1,13,'A','(C) & (E) ') (1,13,'B','(B),(C) & (D)')
>   (1,13,'C','(A), (C) & (E)') (1,13,'D','All of these. ')
>   (1,13,'E','None of these. ') (1,14,'A','private ') (1,14,'B','public')
>   (1,14,'C','protected') (1,14,'D','private OR protected')
>   (1,14,'E','All of the above') (1,15,'A','(C), (D) & (E)')
>   (1,15,'B','(D) ') (1,15,'C','(A), (D) & (E)') (1,15,'D','(D) & (E) ')
>   (1,15,'E','(A)')
>
> ===== users data ====
>
> (1,'1@gmail.com','','George','Ronald','','','Atlanta','GA','30303')
>   (2,'2@gmail.com','','Mary','Erikson','','','San Diego','CA','91901')
>   (3,'3@gmail.com','','John','Washington','','','Atlanta','GA','30314')
>
> ====enrolls data=====
>
> (1,1,to_date('2012/02/15 10:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd
>   hh24:mi:ss'),to_date('2012/02/22 10:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')
>   (2,1,to_date('2012/02/15 10:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd
>   hh24:mi:ss'),to_date('2012/02/22 10:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')
>   (3,1,to_date('2012/02/17 10:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd
>   hh24:mi:ss'),to_date('2012/02/24 10:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')
>   (1,3,to_date('2012/02/17 10:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd
>   hh24:mi:ss'),to_date('2012/02/24 10:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')
>   (2,3,to_date('2012/02/20 10:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd
>   hh24:mi:ss'),to_date('2012/02/27 10:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')
>   (3,3,to_date('2012/02/20 10:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd
>   hh24:mi:ss'),to_date('2012/02/27 10:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')
>
> ===userResponse data====
>
> (1,1,1,'A') (1,1,2,'B') (1,1,3,'A') (1,1,4,'B') (1,1,5,'N')
>   (1,1,6,'C') (1,1,7,'D') (1,1,8,'A') (1,1,9,'B') (1,1,10,'B')
>   (1,1,11,'A') (1,1,12,'B') (1,1,13,'A') (1,1,14,'A') (1,1,15,'A')
>
> (2,1,1,'B') (2,1,2,'B') (2,1,3,'E') (2,1,4,'C') (2,1,5,'D')
>   (2,1,6,'A') (2,1,7,'C') (2,1,8,'B') (2,1,9,'B') (2,1,10,'A')
>   (2,1,11,'A') (2,1,12,'B') (2,1,13,'B') (2,1,14,'A') (2,1,15,'A')
>
> (3,1,1,'C') (3,1,2,'C') (3,1,3,'D') (3,1,4,'D') (3,1,5,'A')
>   (3,1,6,'A') (3,1,7,'D') (3,1,8,'D') (3,1,9,'A') (3,1,10,'A')
>   (3,1,11,'B') (3,1,12,'B') (3,1,13,'A') (3,1,14,'A') (3,1,15,'C')
>
> (1,3,1,'N') (1,3,2,'A') (1,3,3,'A') (1,3,4,'B') (1,3,5,'B')
>   (1,3,6,'C') (1,3,7,'D') (1,3,8,'A') (1,3,9,'A') (1,3,10,'B')
>
> (2,3,1,'B') (2,3,2,'C') (2,3,3,'A') (2,3,4,'C') (2,3,5,'B')
>   (2,3,6,'D') (2,3,7,'D') (2,3,8,'D') (2,3,9,'A') (2,3,10,'A')
>
> (3,3,1,'B') (3,3,2,'A') (3,3,3,'A') (3,3,4,'B') (3,3,5,'B')
>   (3,3,6,'C') (3,3,7,'D') (3,3,8,'A') (3,3,9,'A') (3,3,10,'B')

Thanks,

Comment: remove the, "ur.response = q.correctanswer"  A schema and example data may your get better answers.  You really want to do a left join on the UR and Q where UR.response = q.correctanswer and do an isnull.  However, you're just counting them?

Comment: I tried using left outer join but it still gave an error and I couldn't add the users table after the join.  Could you provide me with code that could lead me in the right direction please.  I am counting the occurences where the user responds with the correct answer, I am looking for the grade basically

Comment: Maybe sample data would help of each table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I think you're asking is "how many questions did any user get right?"  If so, based on the query you have - and the fact that there's no direct relation between users and questions - I've come up with the following:

```
select u.uno, sum(case ur.response when null then 0 else 1 end) as Test1
  from question q
       cross join users u
       left join userresponse ur
         on q.eno = ur.eno
        and q.qno = ur.qno  
        and q.correctanswer = ur.response 
        and u.uno = ur.uno
 where q.eno = '1' 
group by u.uno
```

So we do a cartesion join between `users` and `questions`, because we don't have a better way to join them.  We then do an left outer join against the `userresponse` table; unless everything matches correctly, the user either didn't answer the question or answered it wrong.  We cast whether or not that value's null to a 0 if null and 1 if if it's not, so the sum of those is the number of correct answers per user.

Comment: Fixed SQL.  Perhaps you could have tried harder to fix it yourself.

Comment: I tried however I was not able to figure out the problem, this is wrong, it gives me 15 for all users.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood your query correctly, the following ought to work. It uses the old Oracle join syntax:

```
SELECT u.uno, COUNT(*)
  FROM users u, userresponse ur, question q
 WHERE u.uno = ur.uno
   AND ur.response = q.correctanswer(+)
   AND ur.eno = q.eno(+)
   AND ur.qno = q.qno(+)
   AND q.eno(+) = 1
 GROUP BY u.uno
```

Comment: doesn't work gives 25 for all uers, where the score are suppose to be 0, 2,4

Comment: also, those Oracle specific outer joins make me sad, learn to use ANSI standard `LEFT JOIN` instead!

Comment: @user541597, it would be helpful if you could post your schema. What do the columns (e.g., "eno") and their values represent?

Comment: I think you will find that the second or maybe two that it takes you to type the words "outer join" or "inner join" are well worth the increased readability (ie: lower TAT on maintenance issues) and allows a split between the "join on" and "where" conditions as appropriate between the tables.  Laziness now leads to more work later, as my folks were fond of saying to their kids :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are trying to get all users and the associated quiz score.  If I understood correctly, then using appropriate joins clauses, you can easily get the expected results:

```
select u.uno, count (ur.response) as NumberAnswered, count (q.correctanswer) as NumberCorrect
from users u
join userresponse ur --inner join means we limit user rows to users who have responses
on u.uno = ur.uno
left outer join question q --outer join means we look for row data, but don't exclude users based on the fact that the row doesn't match the join conditions
on ur.response = q.correctanswer
and q.eno = 1 --only include rows where the question.eno value is 1(?)
and q.eno = ur.eno --only include rows where question.eno and userresponse.eno are the same (the answer was correct)
group by u.uno
```

Comment: gives wrong values, result should be 0, 2, 4 gives numbers in the 50s

Comment: Can you post the 'create table' statements (which hopefully also include the foreign key definitions)?